# Add existing migration into schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, schema

I am working on a development project. My `schema.rb` does not contain a table. I can see that there is a migration for the table.

How do I add the existing migration into my schema? I have used `db:drop`, `db:create`, `db:schema:load` but that did not create the table.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to run the migration file:

`bin/rails db:migrate`